# How to run Selenium Grid on Ubutnu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, java, selenium

I have Ubuntu 20 VPS. I would like to run Selenium grid on it. So I have downloaded selenium .jar file and I am able to run hub and nodes on the server.

But as I see I am able to register node from outside the VPS machine e.g. from my local machine like

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://123.456.78.30:4444/grid/register/
```

I don't want to allow this registration. How can I disallow it?

How to force hub to register only nodes via local connection?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it via UFW - uncomplicate firewal :)

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

So now I have only explicitly defined ports open for incoming requests. It means port 4444 is denied for incoming requests.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-configure-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/